# navigation property does not fetch data between two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im using .netcore 5,code first,I have a table which is :

```
          public class PaymentEntity
        {
            public int ID { get; set; } = default!;
            
            public string? QID { get; set; } = default!;

            public string? Status { get; set; } = default!;

            public int? PlatformId { get; set; } = default!;

            public int? CustomerId { get; set; } = default!;

            public string? UpdatedAmount { get; internal set; } = default!;

        }
```

here is my second table which is flagged customer:

```
          public class FlaggedCustomer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
            public string? Comments { get; set; }
            public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
            public DateTimeOffset Modified { get; set; }
            public PaymentEntity? Paymententity { get; set; }

        }
```

every time a new payment comes,if some conditions are not meet,i need to flag the customer and store it in the flagged customer table,here is how i store:

```
 var newFlaggedCustomer= new FlaggedCustomer()
                        {
                            CustomerId = newCustomer.CustomerId,
                            Created = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                            Modified = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                            Comments = "some comments "
                        };
                        dbContext.FlaggedCustomer.Add(newFlaggedCustomer);
                        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

customer can have many payments but only one customerid  can be in the flagged customer,i mean if you have customer id of 2,you can find many payment of customer id 2 in the paymententity but if he is flagged only one customer id 2 can be found on the flagged customer,the thing is the customer is flagged but in the db(FlaggedCustomer) table the field  PaymentHistory  is null,
and when i navigate using Include,returns null,i want to see which payment in the payment history made the customer flagged..any help will be appreciated

Comment: You don' t have PaymentHistory property in FlaggedCustomer class.

Comment: but without that i need to join,join does not give a right answer,because in paymentEntity you can have multiple customer id,how do you want to know which payment caused the customer to be sent to flagged table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to saved your data about the `FlaggedCustomer` and `PaymentEntity`, but in my opinion, whenever a payment is generated, it will be inserted into the `PaymentEntity` table then you need to check if `FlaggedCustomer` should be inserted a new item or just be updated. So there should be some code similar to this:

```
 //insert payment entity anyway
_context.Add<PaymentEntity>(payment);
//check and insert or update FlaggedCustomer
if (_context.Customers.Any(e => e.Id == cus.Id))
{
    var customer = _context.Customers.First(a => a.Id == cus.Id);
    customer.Modified = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
}
else
{
    _context.Add<FlaggedCustomer>(cus);
}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Then when query the payment data to check the payment history, I think we need to use `include` if you set the foreign key or `join` query here which may similar to:

```
var queryResult = from flag_customer in _context.Customers
  join payment_entity in _context.Payment on flag_customer.CustomerId equals payment_entity.CustomerId
  select new
  { 
      CustomerId = flag_customer.CustomerId,
      CreateTime = flag_customer.Created,
      ModifiedTime = flag_customer.Modified,
      PaymentStatus = payment_entity.Status,
      PaymentAmount = payment_entity.UpdatedAmount
  };
```

Comment: flag_customer.CustomerId equals payment_entity.CustomerId does not give a right answer,because in paymentEntity you can have multiple customer id,how do you want to know which payment caused the customer to be sent to flagged table

Comment: According to your description `customer can have many payments but only one customerid can be in the flagged customer`, it should be multiple items in payments which has the same customer id, then trying to find the item which is the first item inserting the table is supposed to be your aim, therefore, how about add a create time stamp for the payment table? Or anyway to make out which is the oldest record.

Comment: but is there any where to have a reference to PaymentEntity table?then i dont need to join or check the date?when the customer is flagged,i can have all the data regarding that day which made him flagged

Comment: It seems that you have a requirement about gathering when a customer is flagged, based on it, I think you need a new table to store the customer id and the first payment information, so that you can get all the "why and when customer is flagged data" by querying that table. In my point of view, there's always a place to save the data so that it can be queried.

Comment: you solution is fine ,im using that,i will add date as well,thanks a lot

Comment: My pleasure sir. Happy coding : )